# Weird behavior with ggplot2 geom_histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I've run into a weird issue regarding `geom_histogram` and it can easily be seen by plotting the uniform distribution.

```
library(tidyverse)
u <- runif(10000)
ggplot(data = as_tibble(u), aes(x = value)) + geom_histogram()
```

Generates the following count histogram:
[image]

It can be seen that it is rather assymetrical, I've read somewhere that this is because the leftmost (and rightmost) bin is centered around 0, and there are no values being generated from -0.5 up to 0, creating the discrepancy seen. So I've fiddled with the `boundary` parameter and it got me:

```
ggplot(data = as_tibble(u), aes(x = value)) + geom_histogram(boundary = 0)
```

[image]

Similarly setting `boundary = 1` made it assymetric at the left.

My questions are: what is the preferred way to fix this behavior? Also, what exactly does the `boundary` argument does? It is not very clear from the docs.

Thank you.

Comment: http://malditobarbudo.xyz/blog/r/starting-bars-and-histograms-at-zero-in-ggplot2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, `boundary` specifies a *spot* to be a split between two bins. The rest of bins are set according to the number of bins or supplied break points. If the supplied `boundary` is outside the range of the data, some clever shifting is done according to the documentation. Maybe with the following examples it becomes clear what `boundary` does.

### workaround

if you set limits for the x axis, you can circumvent the issue, although not a very elegant solution.

```r
library(tidyverse)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.0
set.seed(123)
u <- runif(1000)

p1 <- ggplot(data = as_tibble(u), aes(x = value)) + geom_histogram(boundary = 0)
p2 <- ggplot(data = as_tibble(u), aes(x = value)) + geom_histogram(boundary = 0) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) 

cowplot::plot_grid(p1, p2, nrow = 2)
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
#> `stat_bin()` using `bins = 30`. Pick better value with `binwidth`.
```

[image]

### Boundary examples

in the third plot (p3), `boundary` is set to 0.5 and you can see that two bins are split exactly at 0.5. The same for the fourth plot at the 0.75 point. Boundary is likely not the best name for what it does but basically states that the given number should be the boundary between two bins.

```r
u <- runif(10)
p3 <- ggplot(data = as_tibble(u), aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 22, boundary = .5, binwidth = 0.1) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))

p4 <- ggplot(data = as_tibble(u), aes(x = value)) + 
  geom_histogram(bins = 22, boundary = .75, binwidth = 0.1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 1))


cowplot::plot_grid(p3, p4, nrow = 2)
#> Warning: Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_bar).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: It would be nice if there was a solution that kept the histogram centralized with its values without having to fiddle manually with the limits. Thank you for the detailed answer on the `boundary` argument.

Comment: completely agree, that's why I classified as a workaround and not a solution, but there might be a why to at least programmatically set the limits and reduce manual fiddling. On another level, you might ask if histogram is the best visualisation in this case. maybe a kernel density, which is more flexible and not affected by bin sizes and breaks could be better. Of course that is not the actual question here :)